# How to let user navigate through HTML unordered list with tab key

Tags: html

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

I want to let user navigate through this unordered list with tab key without using `tabindex` attribute. How can I do that?

Comment: why not using tab index?

Comment: you could use javascript. you make a function for key press and when the tab key is pressed you then give some element like the list elements there focus.

Answer (score 1):

with [tabindex](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp)

> The tabindex attribute specifies the tab order of an element (when the "tab" button is used for navigating).

```
<ul>
  <li tabindex="1">Coffee</li>
  <li tabindex="2">Tea</li>
  <li tabindex="3">Milk</li>
</ul>
```